# What is the functional difference between WebSphere Application Server for Developers and WebSphere Base Edition?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I've downloaded the WebSphere Application Server for Developers from here: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/developer/ and have it installed on my local machine.  What, if anything, is different between the Dev Edition and Base?  How can I tell that my running instance is using the "free" edition?

Comment: Version information is included on welcome page of admin console, and is also accessible with versioninfo.bat at <AppServerRoot>/bin folder. If there is anything that will help to distinguish between these versions, it shall be noticeable via these tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is already 1 year old, but here is the answer, in case anyone stumbles upon this page (just like I did): as far as I can see, there is no difference between them.

Extracted from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html):

> The application server is the exact same application server code, which is also identical to the application server code shipped in the WebSphere Application Server product. The platform support provided by the no-charge option is limited to Linux and Windows and the add-on software found in the priced product is not included in the no-charge download version, although most of the add-on software is separately available without charge.

Comment: I've been using the developer edition for a few months now and so far I have not seen a difference.  Btw, thanks for giving this one an answer so long after the fact.